# Maven Multiple POM Project

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have multiple maven projects. In my case there is no parent pom.All other projects are dependent on each other. Here is my project Structure

Project 1 ---- pom.xml(project 2 jar is dependent on project 1)

Project 2 ---- pom.xml(project 3 jar is dependent on project 2)

Project 3 ---- pom.xml(project 5 jar is dependent on project 3)

Project 4 ---- pom.xml(war file)

Project 5 ---- pom.xml(project 5 jar is dependent on project 1)

Project 6 ---- pom.xml(project 5 jar is dependent on project 6)

Project 4 is my main project the project 4 will consist of war file which will be executed on server

My question is what will be build execution of POM structure of Parent Project(project 4) with all other project?

Comment: Can you please draw the directory structure and you do not use a multi module build with parent/child relations?

Answer (score 0):

You should install or deploy each project as a jar and add dependencies to parent project and package as war.

for example in project 5 pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project6</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and in Project 4 pom.xml add all dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project5</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project6</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ......
</dependencies>
```